# Como cambiar el titulo de la etiqueta title y meta descripcion segun el contenido

Tags: php, enlace

mi pagina web esta corformada por modulos y solo tengo una cabesera es decir

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>ejemplo</title>
        <meta name="description" content="ejemplo" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
     link1  link2   link3
    </header>

 <?php

    if(isset($_GET["view"])){

        include"modules/".$_GET["view"].".php";
     }else{

          include"modules/home.php";
       }

  ?>
```

lo demas contenido despues del **body** los traigo desde otros archivos con la super Global **GET** segun el link clickeado, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para cambiar el titulo y la descripccion de la etiqueta meta segun lo traido con la variable `$_GET["view"]` .

esto lo neccecito para mejorar el posicionamiento de mi pagina en **google** y que los usuarios encuentren mi pagina segun lo que buscan, alguna ayuda plis? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usarías algo como (con JavaScript):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content = "Mi nueva descripción"; 
document.title = "Mi nuevo título";
```

Aquí está la respuesta en la cuál yo me base para resolver algo similar que implementé.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47212820/6411462

Espero mi respuesta pueda servirte de algo.